# ASP.NET aspx files and .dll library link?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dll

I’m not a .NET developer guy so I need your help.

## BACKGROUND:

I have inherited ASP.net project. The project is a system that keeps tracks of cash flow transactions. So it has 5 tables in SQLSERVER keeping track of users, projects, banks, transactions and beneficiaries. Users can add projects, banks, transactions and beneficiaries(customers). 
The current state of the software is functional and it has been in service for about 2 years. However changes are needed.
I have managed to run the software on my local machine as an initial step to understand all the layers of BAM – bank account management :

1. SQLSERVER back end
2. View Layer consisting of aspx pages.  IIS has an application BAM that points to the folder. [image: IIS][image: localhost]
   [image: BAM.dll potential cs files]
3. Controller layer in the form of a BAM.dll , or atleast that is my understanding. I found a bunch of .cs files on the BAM live server but they are all auto-generated.

## Questions:

1)  I do not understand how the BAM.dll came to exist if all the C# files are autogenerated. Is there a feature in visual studio that generates the C# from the aspx pages?  Or does it mean that the original C# are needed to compile the  BAM dll and those should be found to continue on? AS you can see from the cs files there name are not human generated 
[image]

Every cs file has this on top

```html
//
<auto-generated>
  // This code was generated by a tool. // Runtime Version:2.0.50727.3603 // // Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if // the code is regenerated. //</auto-generated>
```

2)  In case I want to compile and work on this project how do I approach that? I open a web asp project in visual studio and import the aspx files. I do understand that the aspx files are using the @Page directive and that specifies the MasterPageFile, the CodeBehind  and the Inherits.
e.g. AddTransaction.aspx

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site1.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="AddTransaction.aspx.cs" Inherits="BAM.AddTransaction" %>
```

I do not seem to figure out, for example, how the dll uses the DB connection string in the Web.Config . I ran the project and the BAM.dll uses the connection string which is great but there is a great confusion in my mind as to how the dll is incorporated/compiled in the project, maybe because i can not find the source code?!

> add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="Data Source=Lenovo-PC;Initial Catalog=BAM;User Id=bam;Password=secret;"

3) What would the file/folder structure of this project looks like?

- images folder
- bin folder(contains BAM.dll .pdb)
- DAL folder (contains 1 xml file of country codes)
- Aspx files
- cs folders(compiles into the bin folder)????
- MASTER file
- css file
- Web.config

The BAM.dll obviously has the good stuff, but not those cs# files I found. E.g if you enter a bad username/password you are presented with ‘Invalid User Name or Password’. No other file has that string which makes me believe those cs# are some temporary files during the debugging/compilation.

Comment: You need someone else help - SO is Q&A for concrete questions. Best option would be to find original developer or at least previous person who supported that code. Barring that paying someone who understand ASP.Net/C# may be cheaper option.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are using the compiled version of WebSite, so you need to get the source code, i generate a sample project and the tree file list should look like this:

```
C:.
│   About.aspx
│   About.aspx.cs
│   About.aspx.designer.cs
│   Contact.aspx
│   Contact.aspx.cs
│   Contact.aspx.designer.cs
│   Default.aspx
│   Default.aspx.cs
│   Default.aspx.designer.cs
│   favicon.ico
│   Global.asax
│   Global.asax.cs
│   packages.config
│   Site.Master
│   Site.Master.cs
│   Site.Master.designer.cs
│   Site.Mobile.Master
│   Site.Mobile.Master.cs
│   Site.Mobile.Master.designer.cs
│   ViewSwitcher.ascx
│   ViewSwitcher.ascx.cs
│   ViewSwitcher.ascx.designer.cs
│   Web.config
│   Web.Debug.config
│   Web.Release.config
│   WebApplication1.csproj
│   WebApplication1.csproj.user
│
├───Account
│       Login.aspx
│       Login.aspx.cs
│...
├───App_Data
├───App_Start
│       AuthConfig.cs
│       RouteConfig.cs
│
├───bin│
├───Content
│   │   Site.css
│   │
│   └───themes
│       └───base
│           │   jquery-ui.css
│           │...
│           ├───images
│           │       ui-bg_flat_0_aaaaaa_40x100.png
│           │       ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png
│           │...
│           └───minified
│               │   jquery-ui.min.css
│               │   jquery.ui.accordion.min.css
│               │...
│               └───images
│                       ui-bg_flat_0_aaaaaa_40x100.png
│                       ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png
│                       ui-bg_glass_55_fbf9ee_1x400.png
│...
├───Images
│       accent.png
│       bullet.png
│...
├───obj
├───Properties
│       AssemblyInfo.cs
│
└───Scripts
        jquery-1.8.2.intellisense.js
        jquery-1.8.2.js
```

When you get the correct code:

1. The compiled BAM.dll will be generated with the code obtained
2. When the application requires the connection string, the string is obtained with a code similar to the following

```c#
string connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalSqlServer"].ConnectionString;
```

3. It should be like the structure that i already mentioned
4. If you want to update or add features, you'll need to see some tutorials about ASP.Net and understand how it works

Hope this help

Answer (score 1):

All what i wanted was a confirmation that i was missing the C# files. I thought that there might be a tool in .NET that can generate the controllers directly from the aspx files!!

Fair enough, i got a hold of the original developers and he supplied me with the entire csproject and the pertinent c# files!!